# What gameplay behaviors are random?

Tags: starcraft-2

SC2 is a deterministic game in the sense that there is nothing left to chance. No units get a "20% chance to cause bonus" or anything like that. The same keystrokes will always yield exactly the same result.

But there are *some* elements which have an element of randomness. The importance of this is that there are still some elements of the game which *cannot be predicted*. I'd love to see a list. Here are a couple I can think of right now:

1. Starting situation (spawn location, map, ladder opponent)
2. When an SCV is constructing a building, it moves in seemingly random patterns during construction. If you're lucky, the SCV will move where he can't get sniped.

There are other random things but don't affect the game, like the appearance of a dark templar (scythe or no scythe).

Comment: +1 because I want to know whether SCV construction patterns are random. You're right about there not being many random elements in this game (esp. compared to warcraft 3).

Comment: also, is pathing deterministic or random?  If two targets are in range of a weapon (and no action is given) which one is shot at first?  Assuming equal distant?

Comment: yx_ because it's a fluid map grid, it would be extremely rare to have *exactly* the same distance to two different units, so it's probably safe to just assume it's deterministic in the sense that it will just never happen. It's thus safe to assume they don't generate a random number to pick the target. Past that I don't think we can guess. I am pretty surprised though how much detail stuff like that is deterministic though, like when you box select a bunch of units, they always are in the same order (I think?).

Comment: rule #52 of coding, if you assume it will never happen, it will happen the first time its tested :P  They have to do something to handle that edge case, even if its just picking the western most one first, or something.

Comment: Right, my overall point is "what gameplay actions in SC2 can you *not* strategically use to your advantage". No human could ever use "equidistant target selection" behavior to any strategic advantage, whether it's deterministic or not, so it doesn't really matter. Maybe it's possible to make a custom map which tests it though to make certain :)

Comment: Now I really want to make a starcraft 2 map with two marines, one named "Han", the other named "Greedo", both with a single hitpoint, spawn them, and have them attack move at each other, just to see who shoots first (and if it changes based on their relative cardinal positions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I can think of the following (with 1, 2, 3 and 5 already mentioned by you):

1. Starting locations.
2. Choice of opponent(s).
3. Map choice, if it's random.
4. Race choice, if it's random.
5. SCV movement while building.
6. Larva movement.
7. Larvae location after injection is done.
8. [Creep spread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=133410&currentpage=2) around a creep-generating point.
9. [The time it takes to burrow and unburrow](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Burrow).
10. Interceptor movement pattern (take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=69Fcb2vaYHE#t=20s) - if it wasn't random, all interceptors would have probably taken the same route after the first attack, but they don't).
11. Also, I'm pretty sure there's also a small variance on the viking transformation duration - see [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28561/what-is-the-real-duration-of-the-vikings-transformation).

In any case, while items 5 to 11 do have some concrete gameplay effect, I'd say their impact is very low.

Comment: The viking one is due to available air/ground space. If they are closely grouped together they need to spread out to get up in the air and to land. If you spread them out, they'll all land and get up in the air (tried on a unit tester).

Comment: @Sorean I also tried it on a unit tester when they were well spread-out, but there was still some divergence. Look at their rear engine glow when they come back into the air, it was clearer there they it wasn't simultaneous.

Comment: Creep Spread has since been patched to be more uniform.

Comment: @Oak might just be the early morning eyes not catching it. I'll double check when I get home tonight.

Comment: Now that I think of it from a programming (not progaming) perspective I can see how it would be off. Even though all the units could be sent the same command at a single key press a computer cycle can pass before all the units receive that command. You're probably right about the timing.

Comment: @Sorean in any case we're doing it wrong; comments are not the place, [questions are the place](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28561/what-is-the-real-duration-of-the-vikings-transformation)!

Comment: @tzenes but it's still random, isn't it? Or is there a fixed pattern?

Comment: @Oak, that depends on your definition of the word random.  If you mean random in the mathematical sense, then no it's not random.  If you mean random as the opposite of deterministic, then yes it is random.  It used to be random in the mathematical sense of the word, but that has since been patched for better uniformity.

Comment: Well, random *is* the opposite of deterministic (and if you want to be truly pedantic, *nothing* in video games is random - only pseudorandom).  I think what @tzenes was trying to say, though, is that various aspects of creep spread (speed, direction, timing) used to vary more, but that variance has since been reduced or eliminated.

Comment: @Blue actually that's not what I'm saying.  What I'm saying is there is a correlation between the previous point creep has spread to and the next point it will spread to.  There are even times when the next location is guaranteed to be predictable.  By Mathematically random I mean, unbias.  Creep spread shows bias.

Comment: I'll add another: Which SCVs are selected to load in a command center.

Comment: Creep spread is not really random. If you have two creep tumors in close proximity they will spread faster than alone (even if they are only 1 field away from each other)

Comment: @Tigraine: which exact squares on the building grid get creep is unpredictable (random-ish). It's not uniform in a perfect circle around the tumors.